# How can it work the first time, but fail the second time?

Tags: python, loops, matrix, pygame

In my code I did the same thing twice, but it works only the first time.

```
for y, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for x, color in enumerate(row):
        if matrix[y][x] == 1:
            som = (matrix[y-1][x-1] + matrix[y-1][x] + matrix[y-1][x+1] + matrix[y][x-1] + matrix[y][x+1] + matrix[y+1][x-1] + matrix[y+1][x] + matrix[y+1][x+1])

            if som == (2 or 3):
                matrix[y][x] = 1
            else:
                matrix[y][x] = 0
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)        
        else:
            #here somewhere it goes wrong
            som = (matrix[y-1][x-1] + matrix[y-1][x] + matrix[y-1][x+1] + matrix[y][x-1] + matrix[y][x+1] + matrix[y+1][x-1] + matrix[y+1][x] + matrix[y+1][x+1])

            if som == 3:
                matrix[y][x] = 1
            else:
                matrix[y][x] = 0
```

When I tried this code without the second else, it worked perfect. Now it gives an error: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Also I want that the loop is only repeated when 1 second has passed. When I printed `som` I could see that it only repeated after a second, but on the display from the game, nothing changed until suddenly ten 1s turned into 0s. 
How can I change this, so that after every second the display gets updated?

Comment: `if som == (2 or 3):` _does not_ do what you think it does. Please study the basics of Python before attempting to write such complicated code. Also, what would happen if `x == 0`? You'll end up doing `matrix[y-1][x-1]`, which won't get out of bounds, but will do something relatively odd.

Comment: Another thing to check for: you're modifying your matrix in-place. It looks like you're writing a Conway's Game of Life simulator--if so, you'll want to store the new state separately from the old state.

Answer (score 1):

If you loop over a sequence using `enumerate` then by definition the valid indices are `[0]` to `[x]`. So when you index `[x+1]` you will index out of bounds.

Similarly, when `x == 0` your index `[x-1]` will be `[-1]` which will index the *back* of your sequence, which I doubt is what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that if you were in the first row of the matrix, you were trying to access the row above it (`y-1`) which doesn't exist. The same goes for when you are in the last row and accessing `y+1`, and the same for the `x` axis.

When you access index `y-1` and `y` is `0` it won't throw the exception, but it would actually give you the value from the end of the list. The exception is thrown when the index does not exist in the list.

I've made a lot of changes to your code to reduce repetition. It should be a lot easier to understand what is going on and I've also implemented the checks to stop the `IndexError` and your conditional as mentioned by @ForceBru in the comments.

I have gone with the assumption that if the index doesn't exist, to default the value to 0.

```
for y,row in enumerate(matrix):
    for x,color in enumerate(row):
        center = matrix[y][x]
        top = matrix[y-1][x] if y > 0 else 0
        top_right = matrix[y-1][x+1] if y > 0 and x < len(row)-1 else 0
        right = matrix[y][x+1] if x < len(row)-1 else 0
        bottom_right = matrix[y+1][x+1] if y < len(matrix)-1 and x < len(row)-1 else 0
        bottom = matrix[y+1][x] if y < len(matrix)-1 else 0
        bottom_left = matrix[y+1][x-1] if y < len(matrix)-1 and x > 0 else 0
        left = matrix[y][x-1] if x > 0 else 0
        top_left = matrix[y-1][x-1] if y > 0 and x > 0 else 0
        surround_sum = (top_left + top + top_right + left + right + bottom_left + bottom + bottom_right)
        if center == 1:
            if surround_sum == 2 or surround_sum == 3:
                matrix[y][x] = 1
            else:
                center = 0
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)

        else:
            #here somewhere it goes wrong
            if surround_sum == 3:
                matrix[y][x] = 1
            else:
                matrix[y][x] = 0
```

Comment: I tried this code and now it gives no error, but it also doesn't work anymore

Comment: The rects still heve the same color and don't change anymore